# Main Page Button is missing after user clicks on PageBack button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, slidetoggle

***Functionality:***

When user clicks on a button from page 1, it will bring them to page 2. During the page transition, I have included in a few animation:

1.) Button will explode.
2.) Page 1 will slideout and fade out while page 2 will slidein and fade in and bounce a lil.

**What has been done:**

I have made use of .animate & .toggle jQuery to achieve the following animation during page transition.

**Issue:**
Working fine:

- Page transition: when user clicks from page 1 to page 2 and when user navigates from page 2 to page 1.
- Animation: Button exploding when user clicks on the button and page sliding and fading.

what is not working fine is that when user navigates back from page2 to page 1, the button that performs the explosion animation has disappeared and is not displayed in the original position.

What has happened?

**Code:

```js
function PageTransit() {

  $('#Button1').toggle("explode", {
    duration: slideDuration
  }, {
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });


  $('#Page1').fadeOut({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Page1').animate({
    'left': '1921px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });

  //Method  call to slide and fade in second page to the left padding
  $('#Page2').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Page2').animate({
    'left': '0px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });
}

function Page() {
  console.log("Page");

  $('#Page2').fadeOut({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Page2').animate({
    'left': '1921px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });

  $('#Page1').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Page1').animate({
    'left': '0px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="Page1" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; z-index=1; top:0px; left:0px;">
  <img src="lib/img/Background.png" />
  <button id="Button1" onclick="PageTransit()">
    <img src="lib/img/Button.png">
  </button>

  <button id="Back" onclick="Home()">
    <img src="lib/img/HomeButton.png">
  </button>
</div>

<div id="Page2" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=2; top:0px; left:1921px; ">
  <button id="PageBack" onclick="Page()">
    <img src="lib/img/VideoBackButton.png">
  </button>
</div>
```

**

Comment: There is nothig in `Page()` what puts back the "exploded" button, `$('#Button1').toggle("explode")` may missing

Comment: @cske arh!!!thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As Pointed out by user cske, that you will need to put back the .toggle'explode' at the page back function.

```js
function PageTransit() {

  $('#Button1').toggle("explode", {
    duration: slideDuration
  }, {
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });


  $('#Page1').fadeOut({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Page1').animate({
    'left': '1921px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });

  //Method  call to slide and fade in second page to the left padding
  $('#Page2').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Page2').animate({
    'left': '0px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });
}

function Page() {
  console.log("Page");
  $('#Button1').toggle("explode", {
    duration: slideDuration
  }, {
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Page2').fadeOut({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Page2').animate({
    'left': '1921px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });

  $('#Page1').fadeIn({
    duration: slideDuration,
    queue: false
  });
  $('#Page1').animate({
    'left': '0px'
  }, {
    duration: slideDuration,
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    queue: false
  });
}
```